# Docker Manifest creation fails: unsupported registry version

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I just built two images and pushed them to my registry (docker registry v2), one of them tagged with `hub.domain.com/image:tag-amd64` and the other `hub.domain.com/image:tag-arm64`. Now i want to create `hub.domain.com/image:tag` as a manifest list of both so I can pull the image platform independent.

First I tried to just create the manifest like this:

```
$ docker manifest create hub.domain.com/image:tag hub.domain.com/image:tag-amd64 hub.domain.com/image:tag-arm64
failed to configure transport: unsupported registry version
```

Then I pulled both images to my local machine and then repeated the manifest creation with the same result.

Finally I tried tagging the iamges with local tags `image:tag-a(rm|md)64` respectively and retried the creation:

```
$ docker tag hub.domain.com/image:tag-arm64 image:tag-arm64
$ docker tag hub.domain.com/image:tag-amd64 image:tag-amd64
$ docker manifest create hub.domain.com/image:tag image:tag-amd64 image:tag-arm64
errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
$ # I also logged in with:
$ docker login -u user hub.domain.com
Password: ....
Login Succeeded
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know that i can create multi-platform images with docker buildx, but in this case my dockerfile differs for each platform and I don't know how to merge these into one manifest.